# CoreData + iCloud crossplatform

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data, icloud

I'm writing an app that syncs CoreData between OS X and iOS using iCloud. The issue I'm having is that both iOS and OS X apps are correctly writing data into the cloud, but they are not synced between each other. To be precise:

- I'm currently using a `BSCoreDataController` (https://github.com/adib/BSCoreDataController) which should be usable just fine (see the blog post link in the readme).
- The store options used are: 

  `[options setObject:@(YES) forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
  [options setObject:@(YES) forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
  [options setObject:@"UctoXAccount" forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];`
- While the app is technically document-based, I'm not using any `NSDocument` or `UIDocument` subclasses - all is in-house written. The document is pretty much just a file wrapper package in user-selected place (e.g. iCloud) with the CoreData stuff, I do not support auto-save, or anything similar at this moment.
- When I create a document on the iPhone, it gets synced to OS X, but when opened on OS X (yes, I've waited until all data synced over), the managed object context doesn't contain any objects created on iOS.
- After creating some content on OS X with the same account, the entities are saved correctly, but again, not synced with the iOS content. I am attaching a screenshot of the file package's internal structure.

[image: File Package Internal Structure]

Is there something I'm missing that I need to do to make both sides sync between themselves? Do I need to manually add all persistent stores from within the file package?

Thanks in advance for any help on this subject, this has been troubling me for a long long time now...